# Is this database structure designed efficiently?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I need to setup a DB where users can create categories within categories and inside the categories are multiple objects with multiple different stats

hierarchy example:

```
Cartoon > category
Simpsons > category (within the cartoon category)
Homer > object
Homer object stats > stupidity: 117
Homer object stats > color: yellow
```

I cant just make a table like:

```
-----------------------------
|character| Stupidy | color | 
-----------------------------
|Homer    | 111     |yellow |
```

because i need the users to be able to take away and add different object stats on their own (like add a stat of weight and remove color stats) for each object the stat types will be different plus with thousands of categories i don't want thousands of tables being generated by the users for the different objects.

My DB setup is in the google spreadsheet below which I feel works but I'm not the best with DB setups so I'm checking if there are some  improvements.

I need to be able to display tables from the data displaying all item values that have a relationships with certain categories and/ or objects e.g. all simpsons characters weights or just homers weight.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fHrugYv6JA3id_5zDxWaE-5IUNNGFo5yA1DZ1xQlqtg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I believe you need category and its sub-category then each sub-category has object and its state. Is that you mean. Please confirm to design database for you

Comment: Yes a category with a sub category, each sub category has objects with its state or stats. As long as it holds keys and values for the objects like hair (key), red(value). Thanks!

Comment: ok. plz standby I am going to design it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your database design:

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. There may be many categories and each category may have many sub categories
2. Each sub category may have many objects and
3. Each object may have many keys and values

Cheers!!

Comment: asking someone to mark you up is arrogant and inappropriate. Perhaps others might have other suggestions.

Comment: I am sorry for that but I just kidding

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what i had in mind. I added the sCat_id in the Object_Stats table because i didn't know how to pull Object_Stats rows that were in a subcategory. With this setup if i wanted to get say all keys with the text 'x' in Object_Stats thats Object is in a certain Subcategory.

Comment: you don't need to add sCat_id in Object_stats because this is connected to Objects table that already has sCat_id. Is my answer was helpful to you and is that correct as per your needs?

Comment: Yea i see it works but my main problem now is how to use the db with that setup for trying to get values from the object_value table thats objects are in a certain subcategory. I'm new to 'Joins' do you think this statement would work. `SELECT object_value.value
WHERE object_value.keys == "weight" & objects.subCat_id = "1"
FROM object_value
INNER JOIN objects
ON objects.id = object_value.object_id;`

Comment: This is another discussion but your main question is answered accurately